# WebRTC: View self-view while muting outgoing video in a call

Tags: webrtc

Currently, the video mute functionality in webrtc is achieved by setting the **enabled** property of a video track to false

```js
stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) {
    track.enabled = false;
});
```

But the above code would not only mute the outgoing video, but the local self-view which is rendered using that local stream, also gets black frames.
Is there a way, to ONLY mute the outgoing video frames, but still be able to show a local self-view?

Comment: There are video tracks and audio tracks. If you want to mute a media stream, then disable the AUDIO tracks. However, that disables all the audio associated with that mediastream(which would mean that the receiver would not get any audio). You should probably just mute the video html tag on which you attach your mediastream.

Comment: I think he's talking about video-mute, as opposed to audio-mute, though the question could be clearer about this in places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way yet. Once `MediaStreamTrack.clone()` is supported by browsers, you could clone the video track to get a second instance of it with a separately controllable mute property, and send one track to your self-view and the other to the peerConnection. This would let you turn off video locally and remotely independently.

Today, the only workarounds I know of would be to call getUserMedia twice on Chrome (should work on https at least, where permissions will be persisted so the user won't be prompted twice) which would get you two tracks you could video-mute independently, or on Firefox you could use `RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack()` with a second "fake" video stream from getUserMedia using the non-standard `{ video: true, fake: true }` constraint [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/2bhhe382).

Comment: Yes you are right, the way i went about this to do clone the stream returned by `getUserMedia`. The `MediaStreamTrack.clone()` does work in Chrome atleast. (haven't tried it on Firefox).